# Export print results from Python to csv or excel

Tags: python, list, csv, printing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Vbg.jpg)

```
from jira import JIRA, JIRAError
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import csv
import xlsxwriter 

jiraOptions = {'server': "https://jira.server_link"}
jira = JIRA(options=jiraOptions, basic_auth=("my Jira user ID", "my Jira password"))
df = jira.search_issues('filter=myJira # filter', startAt=block_num*block_size, maxResults=block_size, fields="*")
block_size = 10000
block_num = 0

print(df)

df.to_csv(path_or_buf='data.csv', sep=';', header=header, index=True, index_label='N', mode=mode) -> Error:AttributeError: 'ResultList' object has no attribute 'to_csv
```

'

Dear community,

Any idea how to fix this error? I need to print the filter Jira results to csv/excel. Any ideas please?

Thank you

Comment: your `df` is not a dataframe.

Comment: @Timeless I have included a picture above my listing. Will that do?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you most likely want a tabular format of the result of a [*Search of Issues*](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14) :

```
search_result = jira.search_issues(
    "filter=myJira # filter", startAt=block_num*block_size,
    maxResults=block_size, fields="*"
)

data = [
    [issue.key, issue.id, issue.fields.assignee, issue.fields.status,
     issue.fields.summary, issue.fields.created, issue.fields.updated]
    for issue in search_result
]

header = ["Key", "Id", "Assignee", "Status", "Summary", "Created", "Updated"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

Test/Output :

For :

```
search_result = jira.search_issues("Project=JPOSERVER") # jira.projects()[0]
```

We get :

```
print(df)

            Key       Id Assignee       Status      Summary      Created      Updated
0   JPOSERVE...  1952906     None  Needs Tr...  Document...  2023-06-...  2023-06-...
1   JPOSERVE...  1953011     None  Gatherin...  Thanks f...  2023-06-...  2023-06-...
2   JPOSERVE...  1952899     None  Gatherin...  allow al...  2023-06-...  2023-06-...
..          ...      ...      ...          ...          ...          ...          ...
47  JPOSERVE...  1950141     None       Closed  Cryogen ...  2023-05-...  2023-06-...
48  JPOSERVE...  1950118     None       Closed  Trump's ...  2023-05-...  2023-06-...
49  JPOSERVE...  1949963     None       Closed  Alpha Bi...  2023-05-...  2023-06-...

[50 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: thank you, @timeless, it worked, you intuitively responded to my question.

Comment: I have added a new picture, what if I want to add more labels like OriginalEstimate, Logged time? Pleasee see attached.

Comment: Where did you attached it ? In your post, I can see only this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Vbg.jpg

Comment: data = [
    [issue.key, issue.fields.assignee, issue.fields.status,
     issue.fields.summary, issue.fields.created, issue.fields.updated, issue.fields.timeOriginalEstimate, issue.fields.logged]
    for issue in search_result
]

header = ["Key", "Assignee", "Status", "Summary", "Created", "Updated", "Original_time", "Logged_time"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
print(df)

Comment: I can't upload a new picture. Still searching how to upload it.

Comment: Can you try with lower case : `timeoriginalestimate` ?

Comment: I have taken "alias" from : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/advanced-searching-fields-reference-939938743.html#Advancedsearchingfieldsreference-originalEstimateOriginalEstimateOriginalestimate    for labels values. Is this how you would do it as well @timeless?

Comment: I'm using tab-completion in `Jupyterlab` to get the correct field names with `issue.fields.[TAB]`.

Comment: Simply the best, @timeless. Keep you your good work for the community. I am currently using jupyter notebook, and I don't see tab-completion. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask if you have more questions and happy coding ;)

Comment: Update: actually jupyternotebook also has tab-completion by simply pressing TAB. Thank you for the hint :)

Comment: how do you get all Jira results and not just 1000? E.g. I have:search_result = jira.search_issues(
    "filter=71590", 
    maxResults=10000 (-> this 10k doesn't work, I still get 1000 results), fields=""
)